# How to join + select only customers that have only 1 order?

Tags: mysql, sql

| **CUSTOMERS** |
| --- |
| NAME |
| ID |

| **ORDERS** |
| --- |
| CID |
| ITEMS |

New customer orders in orders table have new data record like:

```
CID 134 - CAR
CID 135 - PHONE
CID 134 - TEA
```

I need to select only customers that have 1 record in the orders table, in dat above its CID 135

IDN=CID

I need to select IDN that have only one ITEMS record, I tried:

```
SELECT customers.name, orders.items
FROM customers JOIN orders
WHERE Items > 2
```

but doesn't work :(

Comment: :( but I writed my tables structure... ID is something like 2313, 1233, 1232 - CID in the second table same 2313, 1233, 1232 (foreign key ID from CUSTOMERS and CID from ORDERS), items its text data like *coffe machine*, *mobile phone*

Comment: The data model is confusing [to me]. Can you add a few rows of sample data and the expected result?

Comment: @TheImpaler added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to modify your where clause. This query will return only customers that have exactly one row in the orders table.

```sql
SELECT customers.name,
  orders.items 
FROM customers 
LEFT JOIN orders 
on customers.ID = orders.CID
WHERE customers.ID IN (SELECT CID from orders GROUP BY CID HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an `ON` statement for your join. This tells SQL how to connect the two tables.

```
SELECT 
  customers.name
  , orders.items 
FROM customers 
JOIN orders 
on customers.ID = orders.CID
WHERE Items > 2
```

Comment: forgot to write ON, this one I know but the main question is *WHERE Items >2*
items have values like: car, mobile phone, coffe
I need to select only NAMES that have 1 record in ORDER table column ITEMS

- I need select persons that ordered only 1 item

Answer (score 1):

You must add a another subquery which count the numbers,

> ```
> CREATE tABLE customers (ID int, name varchar(10))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO customers VALUES (1,'A'),(2,'b')
> ```

> ```
> CREATE tABLE orders (ID int,CID int,items varchar(10))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO orders VALUES (1,1,'car'),(2,1,'car2'),(3,2,'car'),(4,2,'car2'),(5,2,'car2')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>   customers.name
>   , orders.items 
> FROM customers 
> JOIN orders 
> on customers.ID = orders.CID
> INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) countr,CID FROM orders  GROUP BY CID) o1  on o1.CID = orders.CID
> WHERE countr > 2
> ```

> ```
> name | items
> :--- | :----
> b    | car  
> b    | car2 
> b    | car2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8693ad5195ca0a9afd1ac352c9ce8789)*

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select * from customers
where id in (
  select cid from orders group by cid having count(*) = 1
)
```